# Modify the existing traverse logic for backward direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please look at the working demo on  http://jsfiddle.net/amitbas/gyvNW/94/

Now **searchBackward function to search backwards for the content defined in [] relative to the cursor position when shift + Tab is pressed is Not working**. I have put various alert statements inside searchBackward  function 
Please note that searchForward function is working
Please suggest.

The jsfilldle code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').live('keydown', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 9) {
             if (e.shiftKey) {

             var currentIndex = getCaret($(this).get(0));
             searchBackward($(this), currentIndex);
             return e.preventDefault()
            } else {
                var currentIndex = getCaret($(this).get(0));
                 searchForward($(this), currentIndex);
                 return e.preventDefault()
              }  
        }
    });
});



function searchForward(element, currentIndex) {
    var rSearchTerm =  /(\[.*?\]+)/;
    var val = element.val();
    var matchStartPos, matchEndPos;
    var m = val.substr(currentIndex).match(rSearchTerm);
     if (!m){
        currentIndex = 0;
        m = val.match(rSearchTerm);
       }
    console.log(m);
    if (m) {
        matchStartPos = m.index;
        matchEndPos = matchStartPos + m[0].length;
      } else {
        currentIndex = 0;
        matchStartPos = 0;
        matchEndPos = 0;
    }
    var input = element.get(0);
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(matchStartPos + currentIndex, matchEndPos + currentIndex);
    } else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', matchEndPos + 1 + currentIndex);
        range.moveStart('character', matchStartPos + currentIndex);
        range.select();
    }
}
function searchBackward(element, currentIndex) {
 //  var rSearchTerm =  /(\].*?\[+)/;
    var rSearchTerm =  /(\[.*?\]+)/;
    var val = element.val();
 //   alert (val);
    var matchStartPos, matchEndPos;
    var m = val.substr(currentIndex).match(rSearchTerm);
 //   alert ('m is ' + m);
    if (!m){
        currentIndex = 0;
        m = val.match(rSearchTerm);
     //   alert ('!m is ' + m);
    }
   // console.log(m);
    if (m) {
        matchStartPos = m.index;
     //   alert(matchStartPos + 'matchStartPos is');        
        matchEndPos = matchStartPos - m[0].length
      //  alert(matchEndPos + 'matchEndPos is');
    } else {
        currentIndex = 0;
        matchStartPos = 0;
        matchEndPos = 0;
    }
    var input = element.get(0);
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(matchStartPos + currentIndex, matchEndPos + currentIndex);
    } else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', matchEndPos - 1 - currentIndex);
        range.moveStart('character', matchStartPos - currentIndex);
        range.select();
    }
}
function getCaret(el) {
    if (el.selectionEnd) {
        return el.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        el.focus();
        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        if (r == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        var re = el.createTextRange(), rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
        return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code seemed interesting. So I took a look at it.

Here are the changes I made:

The line:

```
var m = val.substr(currentIndex).match(rSearchTerm);
```

becomes:

```
 var m = val.substr(0,currentIndex).match(rSearchTerm);
```

To search from the beginning of text.

The line:

```
matchEndPos = matchStartPos - m[0].length
```

should be the same as on the forward function:

```
matchEndPos = matchStartPos + m[0].length
```

And the line that makes the selection:

```
input.setSelectionRange(matchStartPos + currentIndex, matchEndPos + currentIndex);
```

Should be (to take from line beginning):

```
input.setSelectionRange(matchStartPos , matchEndPos );
```

The result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q62tX/

No... not quite right. It should take the last item that matches.

Comment: Thanks however in example of Hi  Press Tab First [this] is [an] example. Testing [amit] again [this ] and [again ] and [again] So when
in this case , when Shift + Tab is pressed , the focus goes to only [this] and not traverse. The Shift + Tab should behave like Tab but in backward direction only